# Running Identity Server4 on Fargate and Getting Issues with Authentication

Tags: identityserver4, aws-fargate

I 'm trying to run identiyserver4 on AWS Fargate to authenicate two applications.The service is ruuning in fargate and returning details when https://{id_srv_url}/.well-known/openid-configuration.

The id_server is running on ECS Faragate and The application are running on IIS server in EC2 box.WhenI try to access application url the login page is served By Idnetiy server but when enter login detail it is failing authenticate and throwing the following error.

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset does not exist
Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, bool randomKeyContainer)
Stack
Query
Cookies
Headers
WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset does not exist

I verified key in fargate container and it is exist C:\temp folder.I tried to replicate the same secenario in ec2 machine that is running the identity server in separate IIS server ec2 machine and it is working fine.Can any one advice how make this working in aws fargate

Comment: I guess you can't use WindowsCryptographicException if you are running in a Linux container? or are you running in a Windows container?